# Laravel 5.2 - render partial view with its own CSS& JS

Tags: ajax, partial-views, laravel-5

I searched on Mr GOOGLE but no luck,I want to load page contents with ajax.There are two sections which i need to render partially,

- List view
- Map view

Here is my code.

JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    type : 'POST',
    url  : main_path+'/homeservices/getData_Map',
    beforeSend: function(){
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    data: {'_token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')},
    success :  function(data)
    {
      $('#map_hs').html('');
      $("#map_hs").html(data['map_data']);
      $('.list_overmap').empty();
      $('.list_overmap').html(data['list_data']);
     }
  });
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
public function getData_Map() {
    $input = Request::all();
    if(Request::isMethod('post') && Request::ajax()) {
        $hs_list = $this->services_list->getHomeServices();
        $returnHTML = view('homeservices.mapcontents')->with('servicesMap', $hs_list)->render();
        $returnHTML_list = view('homeservices.listcontents')->with('servicesList', $hs_list)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'map_data'=>$returnHTML,'list_data'=>$returnHTML_list));

     }
}
```

I have These files

- Template file *homeservices*
- I have view file
- I have two partial files

Here is my view file

```
@extends('layouts.homeservices')
@section('content')
<div class="list_overmap"></div>
<div id="map_hs" ></div>
@endsection
```

Now, There are different css & js files for each partial files.For example map view has there two extra files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{URL::asset('css/lightslider.css')}}"/>
<script src="{{URL::asset('public/src/js/lightslider.js')}}"></script>
```

Now my code give me error

```
.lightSlider is not a function
```

SO my questions are

- Do i need to include the extra files in partial view only or in template file?
- What is the best place, where i should include js code & file and css code and files related to those partial views?

Note: Please help me solve my problem,i spent too much time to find solution before i post here.

Comment: Hello @DOE , this is my first comment ever, so sorry if I fail.
You can use 
    @stack('scripts')
in any layout.blade.php Template to
`@push('scripts')`
from your homeservices.blade.php Template.
example: I got a app.layout.php with some `@include('content')` and the `@stack('css')` or scripts.
In any Template you can use it like this:
    @push('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/main.css') }}">
    @endpush

//edit: to stupid to mark it as Code.

Answer (score 0):

I only just found this myself, so don't quote me on it, but I believe...

**@yield & @section** - place @yield in the layout where you would like to use @section in the view which you would like to render the content from. **You can only user @section once from any views that extend it**

i.e. Layout (How I usually go about it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    @yield('content')
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

i.e. Child view

```
@extends(app/layout)
@section('styles')
@stop
@section('section')
@stop
@section('scripts')
@stop
```

**@stack & @push** - work the same way, but in my experience you **can call @push many times, from any of view that extends your layout.**

i.e. Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @stack('styles')
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    @yield('content')
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

i.e. Child view

```
@extends(app/layout)
@push('styles')
@endpush
@section('section')
    @include('partial')
@stop
@push('scripts')
@end
```

i.e. partial

```
<h1> Map HTML that you are creating partial for </h1>
<div class="list_overmap"></div>
<div id="map_hs" ></div>
@push('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{URL::asset('css/lightslider.css')}}"/>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
<script src="{{URL::asset('public/src/js/lightslider.js')}}"></script> 
@end
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this is what helped me in a similar situation.